# mySQL query with field replacemnt?

Tags: mysql

I'm need to run a query from mySQL 5.6 which involves looking up date from different tables. I'm new to mySQL and I'm not sure what this operation is called, or else I would have just googled the subject... I'm hoping to get someone to point me in the right direction... Please note, I can't change the structure of the tables, as this is pre-populated from the application I am using.

example:

3 tables in the same local database: network_segments, Buildings, Departments

network_segments description:

```
network_segment_ID, display_name, starting_ip, ending_ip, building, department
1, 10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.254, 1, 2
2, 10.1.0.1, 10.1.0.254, 2, 3
3, 10.4.0.1, 10.4.0.254, 3, 1
```

building table description:

```
building_ID, description
1, ACHQ
2, EHQ
3, AHQ
```

departments table description:

```
department_ID, description
1, marketing
2, sales
3, hr
```

I want to "select * from network_segments" but in stead of the building and department IDs coming back, I'd like the description field for those IDs:

```
1, 10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.254, ACHQ, sales
2, 10.1.0.1, 10.1.0.254, EHQ, hr
3, 10.4.0.1, 10.4.0.254, AHQ, marketing
```

any advise would be appreciated...

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: Hint: Try `join`ing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select network_segment_ID, display_name, starting_ip, ending_ip, bld.description, dept.description
from network_segments
join buildings bld on (building = building_ID)
join departments dept on (department = department_ID);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not generally all that helpful.  Perhaps you could give some indication of why/how that answers the question?

Comment: Yeah, I was a bit at a loss of what to say for such a fundamental question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help Colin 't Hart, and  for the join examples. I couldn't get your exact solution to work, but I got a less elegant version going for my application DB reporting needs.

Below is working code that will combine all of the lookup tables while only displaying the data columns I need. It's not the inline replacement I was hoping for, but I also didn't know what to ask for when I posted earlier.  I've added a union to make the final csv output have headers. This was for the Casper application server by JAMF Software.

Thank you!

```
(select 'Subnet Name','Starting Address','Ending Address','Distribution Point','Software Update Server','Building Name','Department Name')
union
(select n.display_name, n.starting_address, n.ending_address, dps.server_address, s.server_address, b.building_name, d.department_name
from network_segments as n inner join buildings as b
on n.building_id = b.building_id
inner join departments as d
on n.department_id = d.department_id
inner join distribution_points as dps
on n.distribution_point_id = dps.distribution_point_id
inner join software_update_servers as s
on n.software_update_server_id = s.software_update_server_id
INTO OUTFILE 'c:/tmp/network_subnet_report.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n');
```